# Поправить перевод ошибки, возникающей при невозможности загрузить страницу

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно заменить точку на запятую:

> При загрузке элемента возникла ошибка. Пожалуйста, попробуйте ещё раз.

Comment: В какой момент возникло? Если сообщение с правкой удалить?

Comment: @älёxölüt при обновлении страницы нажать крестик до полной загрузки. Можно поймать такое вот сообщение.

Comment: который на груди висит?

Comment: @älёxölüt я атеист :D

Comment: потому и ошибка. Надо бы в тексте перевода это учесть :)

Comment: @älёxölüt "попробуйте помолиться".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/3432

Добавил вариант:

> При загрузке элемента возникла ошибка. Пожалуйста, попробуйте ещё раз.

Comment: Утвердил перевод